# Is it possible to get the installation directory from .msi fles?

Tags: windows-installer

I would like to know what are the directories the files within a .msi package will be installed to. For example, if I run the file `x.msi`, it will likely install its files in `C:\Program Files\Program X`.

Is it possible to get that directory before running the file?

Comment: An .msi installer can extract files to more places than just the Program Files folder. What is exactly your main purpose?

Answer (score 1):

MSI files can be configured to install files anywhere so there isn't any set assumptions you can make.

You can use [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to examine the msi file, specifically, the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tables to see where files are likely to be installed.

You can also try a [vbs script](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToListAllTheFilesInAnMSIInstallerUsingVBSciript.aspx) that automates this process for you, although I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: There are packages with hardcoded paths, but they're probably vastly outnumbered.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have answered, you can get a pretty good idea of what is installed and where by an MSI file by extracting all the files with an admin install:

```
msiexec.exe /a File.msi
```

Then specify an extraction location and the MSI file will be unpacked (cabs will be extracted) and you will get a neat folder hierarchy next to a smaller MSI file - now stripped of its internal cab file content.

Some MSI setups are wrapped in EXE files, and you can run an admin install simply by opening a command prompt and writing **setup.exe /a** and then specify the output path.